# Python не видит переменные

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Я делаю бота в Discord (ну тип self bot) и python не видит переменную ignore_commands но пишет что она не существует когда в коде прописано её существование

```py
ignore_commands = False

client = commands.Bot(["self ", "Self "], self_bot = True)

@client.command()
async def off(ctx):
    if not ignore_commands: return
    
    ignore_commands = False

client.run(" Token ", bot = False)
```

Консоль:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local varible 'ignore_commands' referenced before assigmemt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте переменную глобальной:

```
ignore_commands = False

client = commands.Bot(["self ", "Self "], self_bot = True)

@client.command()
async def off(ctx):
    global ignore_commands
    if not ignore_commands: return
    
    ignore_commands = False

client.run(" Token ", bot = False)
```

Селф боты запрещены [TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/115002192352-%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%84-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-)

Comment: Я дел сэлф бота просто для прикола там Embed, музыка и т.д